# Configuring askbot with apache

Tags: apache-http-server, python, django, mod-wsgi

I am new to Askbot and Apache. Am getting the following error when I start my Apache:

```
[Tue Mar 15 10:25:42.367470 2016] [:info] [pid 6748:tid 139731953211264] mod_wsgi (pid=6748): Attach interpreter ''.

[Tue Mar 15 10:25:48.464013 2016] [:info] [pid 6748:tid 139731953211264] mod_wsgi (pid=6748): Shutdown requested 'askbot2'.

[Tue Mar 15 10:25:48.464132 2016] [:info] [pid 6748:tid 139731953211264] mod_wsgi (pid=6748): Stopping process 'askbot2'.

[Tue Mar 15 10:25:48.464147 2016] [:info] [pid 6748:tid 139731953211264] mod_wsgi (pid=6748): Destroying interpreters.

[Tue Mar 15 10:25:48.464157 2016] [:info] [pid 6748:tid 139731953211264] mod_wsgi (pid=6748): Cleanup interpreter ''.

[Tue Mar 15 10:25:48.466515 2016] [:info] [pid 6748:tid 139731953211264] mod_wsgi (pid=6748): Terminating Python.

[Tue Mar 15 10:25:48.468269 2016] [:info] [pid 6748:tid 139731953211264] mod_wsgi (pid=6748): Python has shutdown.

[Tue Mar 15 10:25:49.662133 2016] [:info] [pid 6868:tid 139779358148480] mod_wsgi (pid=6868): Attach interpreter ''.

[Tue Mar 15 10:26:29.357548 2016] [:info] [pid 6868:tid 139779358148480] mod_wsgi (pid=6868): Shutdown requested 'askbot2'.

[Tue Mar 15 10:26:29.357727 2016] [:info] [pid 6868:tid 139779358148480] mod_wsgi (pid=6868): Stopping process 'askbot2'.

[Tue Mar 15 10:26:29.357752 2016] [:info] [pid 6868:tid 139779358148480] mod_wsgi (pid=6868): Destroying interpreters.

[Tue Mar 15 10:26:29.357771 2016] [:info] [pid 6868:tid 139779358148480] mod_wsgi (pid=6868): Cleanup interpreter ''.

[Tue Mar 15 10:26:29.362974 2016] [:info] [pid 6868:tid 139779358148480] mod_wsgi (pid=6868): Terminating Python.

[Tue Mar 15 10:26:29.367527 2016] [:info] [pid 6868:tid 139779358148480] mod_wsgi (pid=6868): Python has shutdown.
```

My site config file:

```
WSGISocketPrefix ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
<VirtualHost *:8080>

     DocumentRoot /var/www/testweb
     #aliases to serve static media directly
     #will probably need adjustment
     Alias /m/ /var/www/testweb/static/
     Alias /upfiles/  /var/www/testweb/askbot/upfiles/
     <DirectoryMatch "/var/www/testweb/askbot/skins/([^/]+)/media">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </DirectoryMatch>
     <Directory "/var/www/testweb/askbot/upfiles">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </Directory>
     #must be a distinct name within your apache configuration
     WSGIDaemonProcess askbot2
     WSGIProcessGroup askbot2
     WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/testweb/django.wsgi
     #make all admin stuff except media go through secure connection
     <LocationMatch "/admin(?!/media)">
     RewriteEngine on
         RewriteRule /admin(.*)$ https://localhost/admin$1 [L,R=301]
         </LocationMatch>
     CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log common
     ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
     LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. You need to add following to the virtual host:

```
 <Directory "askbot-installation-dir">
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
```